# How to get other Gem helpers into my Engine Gem's tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rubygems, helper, rails-engines

I'm trying to write tests for an engine gem I'm writing.  I'm using Rspec and the tests seem to be running fine.  But whenever a view uses a helper from another gem, such as "will_paginate" or "ransack", I get an "undefined method" error.

I've tried including the other gems in my gem's Gemfile (in addition to the engine.gemspec file) as well as the dummy app's Gemfile, but I get the same error.  I've also tried including the gems in the spec/spec_helper.rb file.

So I've tried most of the things mentioned here:

[Setup RSpec to test a gem (not Rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398262/setup-rspec-to-test-a-gem-not-rails)

Usually, for Rspec tests for a regular Rails app, these helpers seem to be just included some how since I don't have this issue running tests for a regular Rails app.

I also have been needing to namespace my url helpers in the views with something like:
engine.resources_path

I'm not sure if that's a symptom of some configuration I've messed up on.

Everything in the engine runs fine when mounted to another app and viewed on the browser.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out a better approach is to stub out methods from gems since the gem should be testing their own methods anyways.  Please let me know if I'm misunderstanding anything.  Thanks!